$\int _0^{\infty }\:\frac{\cos \left( 3x\right)}{\left(x^2+1\right)\cdot \left(x^2+4\right)}dx$
I know how to integrate this but I'm unable to understand why do we chose $e^{i3z}$ over $\cos(3z)$ while doing the contour integration.
if someone can explain the difference between these choices and how does it affect our integral as R goes to infinity then it would be of great help.
thanks.

Because we want to bound the integral on a semi-circle in the upper half plane, and show it tends to $0$ as $R\to\infty$. It is extremely difficult to bound the trigonometric functions in the complex plane. (unlike the real line) That's why an expression of the form $\sin(ax)$ or $\cos(ax)$ in the numerator is usually replaced by $e^{iaz}$, which is very easy to bound.

$\int^{\infty}{-\infty}e^{imx}f(x)dx =2 \pi \sum{k=0} \text{Res(f(x),$z_k$)} $
where Im($z_k$)>0

The main reason is that $|\cos z|\approx  {1\over 2} e^{|y|}$ when $x$ is fixed and $|y|\to \infty $, while $|e^{iz}|=e^{-y}.$
